# Locally installed R package vignettes not found

Tags: r, documentation, cran

I'm trying to access locally installed vignettes. I issue the `devtools::build_vignettes()` command, and this is the (snipped) output:

```
ℹ Copying vignettes
ℹ Moving doges-family-types.html, doges-terms.html, doges-family-types.R, and doges-terms.R to doc/
ℹ Copying doges-family-types.Rmd and doges-terms.Rmd to doc/
ℹ Building vignette index
```

So all these are installed correctly, and moved to the right directory. However, it does not show up in `browseVignettes`, or by any of the commands:

```
> vignette("doges-terms")
Warning message:
vignette ‘doges-terms’ not found 
> vignette("doges-terms",package="dogesr")
Warning message:
vignette ‘doges-terms’ not found
```

I've tried also `remotes::install_local(build_vignettes = T)`, however this says that it's already installed. Also simply installing by `devtools::install(".")`. Same thing. Any idea of what happens here?

Comment: I don't think you installed the package with the vignettes, you just built them in the source dir.

Comment: @user2554330 I tried several things; one of them shows that the vignette index was built (most of them did, actually)

Comment: You missed my point:  installing things into the directory of your package source will be invisible to `browseVignettes` et al.  You need to install the package with those vignettes into a library on the `.libPaths()` list.  You do that with `R CMD INSTALL pkgname.tar.gz`, or the `devtools` equivalent.

Comment: @user2554330 wouldn't that be the `devtools::install(".")` that I mention in the question?

Comment: That's not the equivalent of `R CMD INSTALL`, which will install regardless of whether the package is already installed.

Comment: @user2564330 could you expand on the difference? This would be very helpful. `devtools::install()` seems to say it just calls `R CMD INSTALL`.

Comment: you have to run `devtools::load_all()` before.